# How find this value of $x,y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

let $x,y\in R$, such

> $$\begin{cases}
> \sqrt{1+(x+y)^2}=-y^6+2x^2y^3+4x^4\\
> \sqrt{2x^2y^2-x^4y^4}\ge 4x^2y^3+5x^3
> \end{cases}$$
>   find the value of  $x,y$.

My try:
since

> $$|xy|\sqrt{2-x^2y^2}\ge 4x^2y^3+5x^3$$

then I can't,it is said this problem is Bulgaria National Olympiad(1979),But I can't find it .Thank you

Comment: $$(1)\iff a^2\ge0\iff\sqrt{1+a^2}\ge1\iff4x^4+2x^2y^3\ge y^6+1$$ $$(2)\iff\sqrt b\in\mathbb{R}\iff b\ge0\iff2x^2y^2\ge x^4y^4\iff|xy|\le\sqrt2$$

Comment: It seems that [these Bulgarians](http://www.imomath.com/othercomp/Bul/BulMO379.pdf) are cool, because Wolfram Alpha suggests that the solution is a complex curve (see the graphs [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+sqr%282x%5E2y%5E2-x%5E4y%5E4%29%3E%3D4x%5E2y%5E3%2B5x%5E3+and+sqr%281%2B%28x%2By%29%5E2%29%3C%3D-y%5E6%2B2x%5E2y%5E3%2B4x%5E4) and [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+sqr%282x%5E2y%5E2-x%5E4y%5E4%29%3E%3D4x%5E2y%5E3%2B5x%5E3+and+sqr%281%2B%28x%2By%29%5E2%29%3E%3D-y%5E6%2B2x%5E2y%5E3%2B4x%5E4)),

Comment: and even its intersection with the $x$-axis is a solution of an equation $16x^8-x^2-1=0$.

Comment: Here's the [PDF file with the problems](http://www.imomath.com/othercomp/Bul/BulMO379.pdf). Not that it'll be much help in actually solving the problem since it doesn't come with a solution manual, but...

Comment: Also, I'm thinking of doing something along the lines of substituting in that $x^2y^3$ term... not sure if that's helpful though.

Answer (score -1):

Surely there's a whole family of solutions to this, if all you know is $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$.  How about trying $y=0$?  Then the first equation becomes
$$
\sqrt{1+x^2}=4x^4
$$
and the second becomes
$$
0 \ge 5x^3,
$$
or $x\le 0$.  The first equation has a solution for negative $x$ (about $-0.7474$), so that's one answer.  Is there something special about the particular solution you need?  (Or does "R" mean something different in Bulgaria?)

Comment: Olympiads pretty much universally expect the general solution—in other words, the complete set of all $x$ and $y$ satisfying these equations, with proof.

Comment: The question does not ask for all the solutions, so this seems fair enough.